# How can one take a screenshot of the DOM (UI) in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project that enlists taking a screenshot of the DOM (UI) as one of its features. I have searched and searched but couldn't find a solution.
Does anybody know as to how this can be achieved ?
PS : I need to find a working solution in ReactJS and not in React native.

Comment: Have you tried using the methods described here: [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots/6678156#6678156)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [repng](https://github.com/jxnblk/repng)? You can render your component directly to a png file this way. Might be the best solution aside from just taking a screenshot yourself.

Hope this helps.